# How to compress jpeg images with webpack "tinypng way"?

Tags: webpack, image-compression

I am using [image-webpack-loader](https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader) to compress images. It works fine with png images, but it's almost not compressing jpeg images.

Example 1:

- Original PNG file: 124 kb
- Loader result: 25 kb
- Tinypng result: 23 kb

Example 2:

- Original JPG file: 567 kb
- Loader result: 563 kb
- Tinypng result: 146 kb

Image loader config: `'image-webpack?{bypassOnDebug: true, progressive: true, optimizationLevel: 1, interlaced: true, pngquant:{quality: 100, nofs: true}}'`

How to get close to tinypng result with jpg images?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation you need to increase `optimizationLevel` to higher value (e.g. 5):

> The optimization level 0 enables a set of optimization  operations
>   that require minimal effort. There will be  no changes to image
>   attributes like bit depth or color  type, and no recompression of
>   existing IDAT datastreams.  The optimization level 1 enables a single
>   IDAT compression  trial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But `optimizationLevel` is applied only to png images. It has no effect at jpeg.

Comment: Yep, [imagemin-jpegtran](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpegtran) have only two options: `progressive` and `arithmetic`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will help you minify jpg images automaticlly without complicated algorithm configurations. It can also help you to encode(and inline) images (behave more flexible than url-loader).

https://github.com/GaoYYYang/image-optimize-loader

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|webp|git|svg|)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'img-optimize-loader',
            options: {
              compress: {
                mode: 'high',
              }
            }
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```